# Set password of a Switch to "C?1sc0" using CLI in Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, packet-tracer, cli

I have been asked to set the password of a Switch to  "C?1sc0" in Cisco Packet Tracer.
The problem is that when i type "?" in CLI it prints out:

```
Router(config)#enable password ?
  7      Specifies a HIDDEN password will follow
  LINE   The UNENCRYPTED (cleartext) 'enable' password
  level  Set exec level password
```

I have been searching the for the solution and i have seen on many forums suggesting to use Ctrl+v but this does not work.

Comment: Using the `<CTRL>-v`, I was able to do this: `Router1(config)#enable password C?1sc0` (copied directly from my terminal application).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

To type in such characters, you must use `<CTRL>-V` (hold down the control key and type V, then your odd character).

Comment: i hold ctrl and type v i than let go of ctrl hold shift and type "/?" btn it does not work

Comment: It works for me: `Router1#? this ? is ? a ? test ?`

Comment: Are you using cisco packet tracer and what version?

Comment: No. Cisco Packet Tracer is too limited. It is designed to get you through CCNA, and it has limitations that will not work for me.

Comment: Ok! So can this be the Packet Tracer not supporting this (Ctrl+V) function?

Comment: I do not know if that supports it.

Comment: @MarikselAzemaj try to hold down LEFT ALT key and then type 63 on numberpad and let go LEFT ALT key again.

Comment: @Cown Still does not work! But good idea!